# every isomorphism of quadrics a linear transformation

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Q: \sum_{i=1}^n a_iX_i^2 = 0$ be a quadric in $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}_k$. Is every automorphism of $Q$ a linear transformation?

This should follow from $\mathrm{Pic}(Q) = \mathbb{Z}$ (except for trivial cases)

Comment: An automorphism induces an isomorphism on Pic, so it either fixes all line bundles or inverts them. On the other hand, morphisms from $Q$ to projective spaces are determined by line bundles (up to linear changes of coordinates)

Comment: The argument @Mariano uses is basically the argument Hartshorne uses in Example 7.1.1, Chapter II where he proves the statement for automorphism of $\mathbb P_k^n$.